# Inline add element to list if condition

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to add an object to a list if some condition?

I want to do this:

```
middleware = ["a",
"b",
"c" if DEBUG,
"d"
]
```

Such that if `DEBUG` is False, the list will be ["a", "b", "d"]

My current best suggestion is this:

```
middleware = ["a",
"b"] + \
(["c"] if DEBUG else []) + \
["d"
]
```

which doesn't look very intuitive

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Why don't you insert/pop after creating the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you can get is using [the additional unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) to unpack a variable length inner `tuple` (or `list`) based on the result of a conditional `if/else` operator:

```
middleware = ["a",
    "b",
    *(("c",) if DEBUG else ()),  # Or if you like brackets, *(["c"] if DEBUG else [])
    "d"
]
```

By using unpacking, you can select between two different inner sequences to unpack, getting the desired result with minimal changes to your desired syntax.

In the specific case of length one strings, the middle line can be simplified to:

```
    *("c" if DEBUG else ""),
```

or even (if `DEBUG` is a boolean, or a `0` or `>0` integer value):

```
    *"c"[:DEBUG], 

    *"c" * DEBUG, # For boolean or 0/1 integers only
```

and those can be expanded to non-length one strings by wrapping in `list` brackets:

```
    *["abc"][:DEBUG], 

    *["abc"] * DEBUG, # For boolean or 0/1 integers only
```

but basically all of these alternatives fall into the "too clever by half" category of programming tricks (if you find yourself doing lots of math or slicing with `bool`s, you're probably being too clever).

Comment: Or `*["c"] * DEBUG` or `*["c"][:DEBUG]`.

Comment: @superbrain Great use of the multiply operator. I've adopted the concept in my answer then.

Comment: @superbrain: Yeah, those are ways to make it work for non-length one strings, but they all fall into the "too clever by half" category too. Any time you find yourself using booleans as numbers, or worse, slice indices, you're being clever for the sake of being clever, and your maintainers will not thank you. :-) I will add them to the answer, mostly because they make me grin.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's being clever but straightforward. At least the `*["c"] * DEBUG` is what I immediately thought when I saw the question (then adopted your slicing as alternative). Or maybe I'm doing that kind of thing too often :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any simpler inline way to do it.

Just write a straightforward `if` statement:

```
middleware = ["a", "b"]
if DEBUG:
    middleware.append("c")
middleware.append("d")
```

or

```
middleware = ["a", "b", "d"]
if DEBUG:
    middleware.insert(2, "c")
```

Another option would be to build the `middleware` list from another list that controls it.

```
mware_with_options = [
    {"name": "a", "type": "always"}, 
    {"name": "b", "type": "always"}, 
    {"name": "c", "type": "debug"}, 
    {"name": "d", "type": "always"}
]
middleware = [item['name'] for item in mware_with_options if item['type'] = "always" or (DEBUG and item['type'] = "debug")]
```

Comment: The `append` approach would make the code look extremely cluttered if there are multiple objects at several indices that need to be conditionally placed, while the `insert` approach is a maintenance nightmare for having to keep track of the right indices to insert into.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Maybe the design that requires this is a problem in the first place.

Comment: Not necessarily a bad design. Django for example uses a list of [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/) plugins to alter its behavior. Some projects such as [this](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/debug/) are designed to be a middleware that should only be inserted into the middleware list if the developer intends to debug. In fact, I bet that is the OP's very use case.

Comment: @blhsing I came up with a more elegant solution using a list of dicts.

Comment: Elegance is in the eyes of the beholder I guess. To me that just seems unnecessarily verbose having to repeat the names of the keys for so many times when they are really just a list of names with some special cases. The question stems from the fact that almost all of the middlewares in the list should be unconditional, with only one or two made conditional, and therefore it would unnecessarily clutter up the code if even the unconditional middlewares have to be accompanied with additional keys or Booleans, when they should be cleanly listed with commas in a normal looking list by default.

Comment: You were the one who floated the idea that there might be lots of them. In that case, it seems appropriate to organize them in a better way than just a flat list with a bunch of conditionals. My method allows for further generalization.

Comment: I used to be a Django developer and our project had about 15 middlewares in the list (although I never looked into using such a debug plugin myself). So I think the OP's request is warranted if one is to add such a conditional plugin in a list of 15 otherwise clean looking names.

Comment: Just randomly Googled for an open-source Django-based project and [this one](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/sandbox/settings.py#L141y) has 13 middlewares in the list.

Comment: @blhsing I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. The longer the list, the more useful it would be to structure it as I've shown.

Comment: What are you talking about? The longest the list, the more unnecessarily verbose your solution would be. Imagine a long list of 50 names with only one of them needing to be conditional. With your dict approach you end up with a long list of dicts of 2 keys and 2 values, when the approach that the OP wants to take would result in a largely normal looking list of names, with just 1 conditional expression in between. If you can't even agree on that I think we just have extremely different standards for what is considered clean and elegant.

Comment: If you need to conditionalize the list, then it's more than just a list, there should be some structure to it. Maybe there are other conditions besides just `DEBUG`.

Comment: You are inventing something that has no use case for. At least not what the OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects in the list are all strings as they are in your question, a somewhat less ugly compromise would be to use an f-string with a `split` instead:

```
middleware = f'''
    a
    b
    {'c' * DEBUG}
    d
'''.split()
```

EDIT: Revised to use the multiply operator with inspiration from @superbrain's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the items in the list are all truthy values, you can use the `and` operator to set the  item to `False` if `DEBUG` is `False`, and then filter the falsey items from the list afterwards:

```
middleware = [
    "a",
    "b",
    DEBUG and "c",
    "d"
]
middleware[:] = filter(None, middleware)
```

or,

```
*middleware, = filter(None, [
    "a",
    "b",
    DEBUG and "c",
    "d"
])
```